# ckeditor - having to set basepath for azure publish - mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, ckeditor

I have an mvc .net app that uses ckeditor.  Works fine on local machine.

When i publish to an azure website, i noticed in fiddler that it was looking for ckeditor files in a path relative to the host and not the scripts folder (as it does when running on local machine).

Did some searching and found a solution where I set the ckeditor basepath:

```
CKEDITOR.basePath = window.location.protocol + '//' + '@Request.Url.Authority' + '@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ckeditor")' + '/';
```

Works, but ugly.  Any ideas as to why I have to employ this solution for publish, and/or any ideas on a more elegant way to set the basepath?

Comment: Thanks, solved my odd bug :)

And I agree it's ugly, but atleast it works.